In a sahih hadith, Prophet Muhammad says how the prophets bodies don't decompose, however the old testament talks about the bones of Joseph & Elisha?
Could you please provide an explanation for this with accuracy

Here's one: Scriptures before the Quran are considered unreliable in Islam. Islam relies only two primary sources, and they are the Quran and Hadith, and both have mentioned that the previous scriptures were changed by the disciples and rabbis from the times of preivous prophets and after them so if a Muslim hears anything from them he should neither say it's false, nor say it's true. Because he might be in error in both cases. Reference in next comment.

An-Nasaa’i and others narrated from the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) that he saw a page of the Torah in the hand of ‘Umar ibn al-Khattaab (may Allah be pleased with him).

He said: “If Moosa were alive, and you were to follow him and leave me, you would go astray.” According to another report: “… he would have no option but to follow me.” According to another version: The face of the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) changed when ‘Umar showed that to him, and one of the Ansaar said to him: O son of al-Khattaab, do you not see the face of the Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him)? ‘Umar said: I am content with Allah as my Lord, Islam is my religion, and Muhammad as my Prophet.

Ibn ‘Abbaas (may Allah be pleased with him) used to say:
How can you ask the people of the Book about anything, when your Book that was revealed to the Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) is more recent, and you read it pure and not tampered with? And He has told you that the People of the Book altered the Book of Allah and changed it, and they wrote the Book with their own hands, and said that it is from Allah, to purchase with it a little price.

There is an extensive answer on this site: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/209007/ruling-on-studying-the-books-of-the-people-of-the-book-for-the-purpose-of-dawah-calling-them-to-islam-and-the-ruling-on-studying-comparative-religion
I am not writing in the answer section because I am pretty sure this question is a duplicate. These comments are just to help you. Lastly, welcome to Islam SE, please go through the tour and read the help center articles.

I can't currently find the post that was the duplicate of this at the moment, I will return to this later. But if someone does find it in the meantime, by all means, flag.

The Islamic belief is that the old testament is corrupted, either in interpretation or even in actual text. As such any discrepancy between Islamic texts and the previous ones don't require any explanation beyond saying that the current bible is wrong.
However the story about Moses عليه السلام and the Bani Israel taking away the bones of Joseph عليه السلام  with them when they left Egypt is also mentioned in ahadith - see Sahih Ibn Hibban. 'Bones' are understood to mean the body, even if it is not decomposed.
